# Remove Even Elements after their Addition in an ArrayList and return modified ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

```
package com.company;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static int processArray(ArrayList<Integer> array) {

    int sum=0;
    for (int i=0;i<array.size()-1;i++) {
            if (array(i) %2 == 0 && array.get(i+1)%2==0){
                    sum += array.get(i);
                    array.set(i,sum);
                    array.remove(i+1);
                    i--;
            }
    }
    return array.size();
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(in.hasNextInt()) {
        int num = in.nextInt();
        if (num < 0)
            break;
        arrayList.add(new Integer(num));
    }
    int new_length = processArray(arrayList);
    for(int i=0; i<new_length; i++)
        System.out.println(arrayList.get(i));
}
}
```

=======================================

Input

3
6
36
61
121
66
26
376
661
6
-1

I need Output to be

3
42
61
121
468
661
6

My Output

3
6
42
61
121
66
92
468
661
6

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: *"What am i doing wrong here?"* You never call `remove`.

Comment: @ Andreas if i add  arrayList1.remove(i); my output is still not right I get this output 3
42
61
121
92
376
661
6

Comment: What is the purpose of `%arrayList1.size()`? Get rid of it. --- Why `sum +=` when you always set `sum = 0` first? --- Adding `remove` should fix it, so maybe you added it in wrong place.

Comment: @ Andreas if i remove %arrayList1.size() i get an error                Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since others are trying (and failing) to give you working solution, here it is, with comments on changed lines:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> processArray(ArrayList<Integer> array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size() - 1; i++) { // don't process last value (it has no next value)
        if (array.get(i) % 2 == 0 && array.get(i+1) % 2 == 0) {
            int sum = array.get(i) + array.get(i+1); // add current and next value
            array.set(i, sum); // update current value
            array.remove(i+1); // remove next value
            i--; // make sure we re-process current value, to compare with "new" next value
        }
    }
    return array; // return modified array
}
```

Comment: return array; Error => Error:(20, 16) java: incompatible types: java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to int

Comment: Because you didn't change `main()`. You should be able to fix that yourself.

Comment: But then he won't get a sum of even indexed numbers, and that seems to be what he wants (too), right? Sure, you can simply remove that line, but that doesn't seem to meet (his) specs. I guess he should specify more clearly what he *really* wants.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Which part of question says *anything* about even indexes? *"Remove Even Elements"* means elements with even *values*, not *indexes*, which should be clear when you look at question code, and the given expected output.

Comment: Hmmm... I looked at the wrong code, sorry. There was a line with "Sum of even indexed integers" in one of the answers, and that was still in my editor. I thought I had the original code open.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Yeah, [that dude](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43559472/5221149) is totally confused, because his code is not even doing that either.

Answer (score -1):

Try this below code. This will calculate sum of all even index digits entered in arraylist, removes the even indexed digits and you will have the altered list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main1 {
    public static int processArray(ArrayList<Integer> array) {

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            if (array.get(i) % 2 == 0) {
                sum += array.get(i);
                array.remove(i);
            }
        }
        return sum;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (in.hasNextInt()) {
            int num = in.nextInt();
            if (num < 0)
                break;
            arrayList.add(new Integer(num));
        }
        int sum = processArray(arrayList);
        System.out.println("Sum of even index numbers " + sum);
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++)
            System.out.println(arrayList.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Question is not about even indexes, and is not about summing all even numbers. Question is about *merging* consecutive even numbers by adding them together.